# Leaking sink drain. Possible defective drain assembly?

Tags: leak, drain

I replaced the drain on my bathroom sink, but I'm getting a slow leak when draining water.  I've checked and re-checked the P-trap, the rubber gasket at the bottom of the sink, and the wall drainpipe.  The water is definitely oozing through the seam between the brass body around the stopper joint and the drain pipe below.

I was thinking of trying to apply some silicone to that seam.  Would I be better off replacing the drain assembly completely?

[image: Drain assembly with leak]

Comment: Yes, it does look problematic. Were the tee fitting and the pipe threaded together? Did you apply plumber putty or tape?

Comment: @r13 some folks don’t realize those are threaded together, I would use PFTE tape or dope they both do the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teflon thread sealant would be my first choice, with pipe dope running second.

Unscrew the pipe from the brass fitting, clean up the threads, apply the sealant and reassemble.

The Teflon sealant also acts as a lubricant making it easier to tighten the connection.

Comment: Dope is usually referring to a liquid form of sealant over tape I have both containing PFTE (Teflon) so there might be no difference in reality but other than that I agree with your answer and r13’s comment. ++

Answer (score 0):

Some plastic gasket in that connection supposed to be. Check if you install it properly, sharp edge down to plastic pipe. If it is, just tighten it , may use he pump-player.